# Replacing all vowels in string with String.join() and split() methods

Tags: java, string, replace

I need to replace every vowels in a given string with the same vowel, followed by the letter "v", followed by the vowel a second time. As an example: `bad` should become `bavad`, `egg` becomes `evegg`, `doge` becomes `dovogeve`, etc. The exercise explicitly states that it needs to be done with `String.join()` method. So far, I've come up with
this.

```
String string = "bad";
int length = string.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    char c = string.charAt(i);
    if (isVowel(c)) {
        string = String.join(c + "v" + c, string.split("" + c));
        length += 2;
        i += 2;
    }
}
System.out.println(string);
```

The following `isVowel` method is a simple method to check whether a given char is a vowel or not

```
public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    return Arrays.asList('a', 'u', 'o', 'e', 'i').contains(c);
}
```

This solution is working fine for strings like `bad`, `sad`, `step`, etc. However, if I try it with `aeiou`, the output is `avaeveiviovo` instead of `avaeveiviovouvu`.

Comment: It seems like you are not checking the last character

Comment: You'd make this a lot easier on yourself if you used a new string (preferably `StringBuilder`) instead of manipulating the same string variable.

Comment: How does your code handle words with multiple same vowels like `baba`?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider how would it be significantly easier? Besides, his requirements are to use `String.join()`.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider While I agree with `StringBuilder` with be far easier, the task is asking to use `String.join()` method

Comment: @Kayaman With `baba` it throws IOOB error, index 5 out of 5, while with string `aae` I get `avavavavavavavaavavavavavavavae`

Comment: What about words like ` vacuum`? I would presume would be `vavacuvuuvum`.

Comment: @WJS With `vacuum` the output is `vavacuvuvuvuvuvuvuvuuvuvuvuvuvuvuvum`

Comment: Iterate the vowels instead: `for(char c : vowels) string = String.join(c + "v" + c, string.split("" + c, -1));`.

Comment: @rsfan23 I mean what is the output supposed to be?

Comment: @WJS Sorry I misunderstood your question, yes with `vacuum` the expected output would be `vavacuvuuvum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a String to store the result

```
String string = "aeiou";
int length = string.length();
String result = "";

for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    char c = string.charAt(i);

    if(isVowel(c)) 
       result += String.join(result, c+"v"+c);
    else
       result += c;
}

System.out.println(result);   //Output "avaeveiviovouvu"
```

Comment: This seems to be working just as I wanted, thank you!

Comment: Actually string concatenation in the loop is a really **bad idea**. You should use `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.

```
String[] data = {"bad", "happy", "computer", "java", "vacuum"};
for (String word : data) {
     System.out.printf("%-10s --> %s%n",word,modVowels(word));
}
```

prints

```
bad        --> bavad
happy      --> havappy
computer   --> covompuvutever
java       --> javavava
vacuum     --> vavacuvuuvum
```

- initialize `newString` to an empty string
- then split the word into individual strings of one character.
- if the character is a vowel, append the modified string.
- else just append the character.
- then return the result.

```
public static String modVowels(String word) {
    String[] chars = word.split("");
    String newString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        String ch = chars[i];
        if ("aeiou".contains(ch)) {
            ch = ch+"v"+ch;
        }
        newString = String.join("",newString, ch);
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, `chars[i] = chars[i] + "v" + chars[i];` and `return String.join("", chars);` to avoid `newString` and joining in every iteration.

Comment: Very similar to @Rob answer, which is also working so thank you for the help, much appreciated. Unfortunately I can accept only 1 answer as correct, so here's my upvote!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others in the comments, your code has many other issues and edge cases apart from what you've noticed. But I'll be answering just your original question. `u` is not joined because of how [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) behaves (emphasis mine):

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>
> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

So while `a` splits to be `["", "eiou"]`, `u` becomes `[avaeveiviovo]` and there is no empty string to join with.

Comment: So `split()` with a limit of `-1` would leave the trailing empty array and it would work.